# If-Else logic flow

Tags: if-statement, logic, pseudocode

Can anyone explain to me why the distribution for this code:

```
InfectionHistory <- rep(1,100)
for(x in 1:99)
{
  r <- runif(1)
  print(r)
  if(InfectionHistory[x]==1)
  {
    if(r < 0.04)
    {
      InfectionHistory[x+1] <- 2
    }
    else
    {
      InfectionHistory[x+1] <- InfectionHistory[x]
    }
  }
  if(InfectionHistory[x]==2)
  {
    if(r < 0.11)
    {
      InfectionHistory[x+1] <- 1
    }
    else
    {
      InfectionHistory[x+1] <- InfectionHistory[x]
    }
  }
}
plot(InfectionHistory, xlab = "Day", ylab = "State", main = "Patient Status per Day", type = "o")
```

is different from this code:

```
InfectionHistory <- rep(1,100)
for(x in 1:99)
{
  r <- runif(1)
  print(r)
  if((InfectionHistory[x]==1)&&(r < 0.04))
  {
    InfectionHistory[x+1] <- 2
  }
  if((InfectionHistory[x]==2)&&(r < 0.11))
  {
    InfectionHistory[x+1] <- 1 
  }
}
plot(InfectionHistory, xlab = "Day", ylab = "State", main = "Patient Status per Day", type = "o")
```

I feel like it has to do with the logic of if-else statements. The objective of the code is to simulate an infection model along the lines of a Markov chain

Answer (score 0):

The first example contains `if else` pairs nested within `if` statements.

The second example contains `if` statements with compound conditions.

Upon cursory review, it looks like each example should do the same thing.  This code serves as an example that nested `if` statements can be rewritten as `if` statements with compound conditions.

For example, in example 1, when we get to this line of code:

```
if(r < 0.04)
{
  InfectionHistory[x+1] <- 2
}
```

We already know that

```
InfectionHistory[x]==1
```

has returned `true`, or else we wouldn't be within the body of the `if` that checked this condition.

In the second example, this is simply rewritten as:

```
if((InfectionHistory[x]==1)&&(r < 0.04))
{
    InfectionHistory[x+1] <- 2
}
```

---

EDIT: Looking at it again, the second example doesn't seem to have a case for handling:

```
else
{
  InfectionHistory[x+1] <- InfectionHistory[x]
}
```

This bit of code is repeated in the first example.  It is paired with both nested `if` statements.  The second example could easily be rewritten to handle this however with a simple `if else if else` structure.  For example:

```
if((InfectionHistory[x]==1)&&(r < 0.04))
{
    InfectionHistory[x+1] <- 2
}
else if((InfectionHistory[x]==2)&&(r < 0.11))
{
    InfectionHistory[x+1] <- 1 
}
else
{
    InfectionHistory[x+1] <- InfectionHistory[x]
}
```

Comment: Right, but I'm looking as to what's causing the tremendous difference in frequencies. Ex 1 gives more 2's in InfectionHistory than Ex 2 does. What's causing that to happen? From my understanding, if the two blocks of code were logical equivalents, they should be returning very similar distributions of 1's and 2's.

Comment: @user2938366 I don't know anything about infection models or Markov chains.  Have you tried changing example 2 to the last code block in my answer?